# How does Wordpress rewrite the URL without a rewrite map?

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite

The .htaccess file for a wordpress site looks something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

...and there is no rewrite map set in htdocs. How does this work? How does Apache know how to rewrite these url?

Comment: Done - thanks for the heads up JMC.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Apache does not know. All the requests are sent to `index.php` and Wordpress keeps an internal log of which page to redirect where, and it redirects it. So, in essence, Wordpress actually has two sets of rewrite rules, one internally and a "greedy" external rule in your .htaccess which basically makes all requests refer to the internal rewrite rules.

You may be interested in using [this plugin](http://www.dagondesign.com/articles/wordpress-internal-rewrite-viewer-plugin/) which shows all the internal rewrites that Wordpress is doing itself.