# URL Rewrite Map and Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect, url-rewriting, iis-7.5, http-status-code-301

I am working on a migration from ASP.NET to Wordpress and I want to put 301 redirect rules in place using a Rewrite Map with URL Rewrite in IIS 7.5.  I have all the redirects in a file named rewritemap.config, and I've created the redirect rule in URL Rewrite in IIS, but I can't get the redirect to work with Wordpress.  I don't know if this is possible with Wordpress having it's own rewrite rule in the web.config as well to send everything to index.php where it handles it's own rewrites internally as explained in this link:

[How does Wordpress rewrite the URL without a rewrite map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785840/how-does-wordpress-rewrite-the-url-without-a-rewrite-map)

The XML for the web.config is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rewriteMaps configSource="rewritemap.config" />   
      <rules>

                <rule name="Redirect old links from redirect map" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" negate="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{Redirects:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>


                <rule name="wordpress" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>

      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The XML for the rewritemap.config file was created by IIS Admin so I expect that it is correct and it matches the format I've seen on other blog posts that have shown how to do this.  Am I attempting something impossible with this?  I have hundreds of old aspx pages I need to 301 redirect to specific links in the Wordpress site and there are to many external references to the old links to even think about not having the 301 redirects in place.

Comment: You might have an easier time using the Wordpress Redirection plugin here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/ It supports specific address redirection and regexp redirection.

Comment: Thanks! I already had that installed for 404 logging so now i feel like a real dope. I didn't even think about it for this. I have a solution but I am still curious about why the URL Rewrite doesn't work. I'll close this in a day or two if no one can explain that part so it doesn't remain open.

Comment: I believe that particular plugin attempts to alter your .htaccess file on your behalf. .htaccess files are used to dictate settings for Apache servers, web.config files are their IIS equivalent. Because you are using IIS, I assume the plugin doesn't see a .htaccess file and therefore can't do URL Rewrites.

Comment: Did you ever make more headway with a Map and WP Permalinks? Running two sites with URL Rewrites to the sub-folders where WP is installed. Can't use custom permalinks, keeps rewriting wrong and I get 404.